# Material Design Lite All Elements Loaded JS Callback

Tags: javascript, material-design-lite

I have a page where I'm trying to render a header with MDL and then preload some images. Unfortunately, I'm running into a problem where the image preload function actually blocks the library from properly rendering elements until all the images are done preloading.

I've tried putting the preload function in a timeOut with 2 seconds, but while that works for most fast connections, on slow enough connections, the same problem seems to arise.

As a result, I'm looking for a way to be able to tell through Javascript when the library is done loading and executing - when all the elements are rendered properly. Is there a callback that MDL fires off that I can use to then begin preloading iamges?

Or is there a better alternative solution?

Comment: I'm not sure if this will work for MDL but it's something https://perishablepress.com/a-way-to-preload-images-without-javascript-that-is-so-much-better/ Also you can just use the normal JavaScript `onload` function. It is executed once absolutely all code, files, images are loaded (recall things with `display:hidden;` are not loaded on page load

Comment: you want lazy loading images?

Comment: @AlexeiDarmin The problem with that first link is that MDL doesn't execute until the page is done loading, so adding all the images into the markup directly has the same problem. Same with onload - MDL doesn't run until the page is done loading.

Comment: @YOU Not exactly - I want to preload the images so they're in cache (they're not displayed on this page - they're being cached for a later page). I just don't want the preload to start until MDL is done doing its thing.

Comment: when img tag is inserted to dom, browser start loading and wait until they are loaded. if you don't want to load before MDL, then lazy loading images is the only way, IMO.

Answer (score 1):

Use the `mdl-componentupgraded` event. Check the event's target and see if it is the layout component to start. I bet it is layout causing the problems here due to how we did it for legacy browser support. If it isn't layout, then just hunt and peck around until you find the piece causing the problem.